# I am getting the wrong answer when I use .size() in my for loop but when I assign it to a variable before, it works. Why?

Tags: loops

```
while(!q.empty())
        {
            depth++;
            //int size = q.size();
            for(int i = 0; i<q.size;i++)
            {
                cout << q.size();
                auto currNode = q.front();
                q.pop();
                for(auto n: currNode->children)
                {
                    if(n)
                        q.push(n);
                }
                
            }
```

I using BFS to solve a leetcode problem but when I have q.size() in the for loop, I miss test cases. However when I assign it to an integer before going into the loop (the commented out section), then it works. Could anyone explain why? I would have assumed that the code would work the same written either way. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The size of the queue is always changing inside the for loop.

Let's say initially the size of the queue is 5.

When you store this value in a variable before the for loop, the loop is **guaranteed** to run for 5 times according to the loop's condition.

But if we use `q.size()` in the loop's condition, it will not be guaranteed to run for 5 times. Because inside the loop, the queue's size is always changing. Either it's decreasing because the current node has no child, or it's increasing because the current node has 2 or more child.

Let's say, among the 5 nodes, the first 4 does not have any child. In that case, the for loop will iterate for 3 times and then terminate. But if we use the `size` variable, it will iterate for 5 times.